# What's the term for a comma that commences non-restrictive clauses?

Tags: commas

You pine to use a comma, to clarify that John has just one ball. Is there a term for the mandatory comma that I embolded?

> In each of these examples, the phrase set off by commas can
> be eliminated without destroying the meaning of the sentence.
> Remember, however, that there are some phrases that do not merely
> describe a quality of a noun or verb but instead positively identify it.
> An identifying phrase should not be set off by commas. To take an
> earlier example, the following sentence includes a descriptive phrase
> that can be eliminated without damaging the sense of the sentence
> and therefore can be set aside by commas:

> > John threw the ball **,** **[What's this comma called?]** which was coming apart at the seams.

> If you wish to indicate that John picked one particular ball out of a
> selection of many, you would delete the comma, writing:

> > John threw the ball which was coming apart at the seams.

Stacie Strong. [BA English literature (UC Davis 1986), MPW (USC 1990), JD (Duke 1994), PhD Law (Cambridge 2002), DPhil (Oxford 2003)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/s-i-strong-50b82832/). *How to Write Law Essays & Exams* 5 Ed 2018. 149.

Comment: I would say that it was a _parenthetical_ comma. Usually these come in pairs surrounding a phrase which gives additional information in the same way that brackets do but in this case the sentence ends with the parenthesis so no final comma is needed. If the writer had said "John threw the ball, _which was coming apart at the seams_, into the waste bin" the parenthetical nature of the clause would have been clearer.

Comment: I looked at 5 sources discussing non-restrictive causes, and they all just called it a "comma". The expression between commas is certainly parenthetical, so BoldBen's definition seems the best you'll get, but other expressions (things which aren't non-restrictive clauses) delimited by commas can also be parenthetical. If you want to be precise call it "the comma introducing a non-restrictive clause".